# What is the probability that a convex polyhedron will land on each of its faces if thrown as a die?

Tags: probability, geometry, solid-geometry

Given an arbitrary convex polyhedron that we are using as a die, is it possible to know the probability of it landing on each face? I am assuming that these probabilities depend on the shape of each polyhedron.

I am aware that the problem is physical in nature and that the randomness of a dice throw is produced by chaotic equations of motion and non-conservative influences on the system and etc... I was thinking about whether there was an interesting framework to abstract the problem away from physics and into mathematics.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46684/fair-but-irregular-polyhedral-dice